Interpretation of the theorems of Menelaus and Desargues
I am relearning some affine geometry and I came upon the classical theorems such as Thales, Ceva, Menelaus and Desargues. For the last two of these, I always struggled to get some geometric insight from the theorems.
Thales' theorem lays the foundation for the study of similar triangles. Ceva's theorem shows that the centroid and orthocenter of a triangle exist because the condition for the three lines to intersect is satisfied.
For Menelaus' and Desargues' theorems, I struggle to learn something more general than "in such and such special case, we can solve this olympiad problem in one line". I already know that Menelaus is Ceva's projective dual and that Desargues is self-dual so they have some theoretical significance.
I guess what I'm looking for is what these theorems can teach me about geometry. Do they tell me something new and accessible about the nature of triangles? Do they allow me to view old material in a new light? Or maybe what geometrical questions would lead me down the path of eventually rediscovering these theorems.
An answer to any of these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Do you (not) see Desargues' theorem at work everywhere you look in your house or city?

To answer your question, I'd say Menelaus' Theorem is really, really substantial for proving collinearity in geometry. See Pascal's Theorem, Pappus' Hexagon Theorem, and Monge's Theorem, for example. One of the simplest proofs for these theorems rely on Menelaus' Theorem.
As for Desargues' Theorem, this theorem aids in projective geometry.
